# Delete a value from Java script Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, dictionary, object

I want to know how to delete a specific value from an object containing multi values

this how my object looks like

```
{
  'how can i change my password?': [
    'how can I change my password?',
    'how may I change my password?',
    'how am I able to change my password?'],

'how do i change my password?': [
    'how may I change my password?',
    'how can I change my password?',
    'how should I change my password?',
    'how would I change my password?',
    'how do I change my password?']
}
```

What i want to do is making a search for **how can i change my password** value, whenever i find it i want to delete this value.

If searched a little bit and all i found was talking about deleting the whole object or deleting a complete property using **delete**, but this is not what i want.. i want to just delete a single value from an array of values.

expected output :

```
{
  'how can i change my password?': [
    'how may I change my password?',
    'how am I able to change my password?'],

'how do i change my password?': [
    'how may I change my password?',
    'how should I change my password?',
    'how would I change my password?',
    'how do I change my password?']
}
```

Comment: please share the expected output, btw what you have you tried?

Comment: have you tried using filter.?

Comment: it's updated by the expected output .. i tried to loop through the values and get the value i want, but i couldn't figure out how to remove this value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting from Objects and from Arrays are 2 different things.

**Deleting from an Object**

```
let obj = { a: [1,2,3], b: [4,5,6], c: [7,8,9] };

// delete b from Object obj
delete obj.b;

// obj is { a: [1,2,3], c: [7,8,9] }
```

**Deleting from an Array**

```
let obj = { a: [1,2,3], b: [4,5,6], c: [7,8,9] };

// delete 2 from Array obj.a
obj.a = obj.a.filter(r => r !== 2);

// obj is { a: [ 1, 3 ], b: [ 4, 5, 6 ], c: [ 7, 8, 9 ] }
```

**Don't use delete on an Array**

```
let obj = { a: [1,2,3], b: [4,5,6], c: [7,8,9] };

// delete by key on Array obj.a 
delete obj.a[2]; // 2 is a key, not a value

// obj is { a: [ 1, 2, <1 empty item> ], b: [ 4, 5, 6 ], c: [ 7, 8, 9 ] }
```

In your case, you should iterate over your object's values and filter their arrays.

Answer (score 1):

> i want to just delete a single value from an array of values.

If you just want to remove one value from the array and you know its index you can remove a specific index in an array using the splice method.

```
 const obj = {
    'how can i change my password?': [
        'how can I change my password?',
        'how may I change my password?',
        'how am I able to change my password?'],
    'how do i change my password?': [
        'how may I change my password?',
        'how can I change my password?',
        'how should I change my password?',
        'how would I change my password?',
        'how do I change my password?']
}

obj['how can i change my password?'].splice(1, 1);

// obj is now

{
    'how can i change my password?': [
        'how can I change my password?',        
        'how am I able to change my password?'],
    'how do i change my password?': [
        'how may I change my password?',
        'how can I change my password?',
        'how should I change my password?',
        'how would I change my password?',
        'how do I change my password?']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
loop through all the keys and use filter.

```
const obj = {
  'how can i change my password?': [
    'how can I change my password?',
    'how may I change my password?',
    'how am I able to change my password?'],

'how do i change my password?': [
    'how may I change my password?',
    'how can I change my password?',
    'how should I change my password?',
    'how would I change my password?',
    'how do I change my password?']
}


Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  obj[key] = obj[key].filter(value => value != 'how can I change my password?')
})

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can itrate through all the properties od the object and check the property array contain the query or not then delete or remove the item

```
    let obj = {
      'how can i change my password?': [
        'how can I change my password?',
        'how may I change my password?',
        'how am I able to change my password?'],
    
    'how do i change my password?': [
        'how may I change my password?',
        'how can I change my password?',
        'how should I change my password?',
        'how would I change my password?',
        'how do I change my password?']
    }
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        
      const result = obj[key].filter(item => item != 'how can I change my password?')
obj[key] = result;
    }
}
```